# concat in RxJava2 and first() function

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm migrating my repository pattern to RxJava2. My old code look like

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Post>> getPost() {
    return Observable.concat(mAppLocalDataStore.getPost(), mAppRemoteDataStore.getPost())
            .first(new Func1<List<Post>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(List<Post> posts) {
                    return posts != null;
                }
            });
}
```

However, I don't know how to replace it in RxJava2, how to call posts.upToDate() with my current code?

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Post>> getPost() {
    List<Post> list = new ArrayList<>();
    return Observable.concat(mAppLocalDataStore.getPost(), mAppRemoteDataStore.getPost())
            .first(list)
            .toObservable();
}
```

Comment: What is `posts.upToDate()`?

Comment: According to  https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0 . Use use filter(predicate).first() instead.

Comment: Thank you @PhoenixWang, works!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @PhoenixWang for the hint. This is the solution.

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Post>> getPost() {
    return Observable.concat(mAppLocalDataStore.getPost(), mAppRemoteDataStore.getPost())
            .filter(new Predicate<List<Post>>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(@NonNull List<Post> posts) throws Exception {
                    return isUpToDate(posts);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hit the local store, if nothing is in the local store you just try the remote one? I used the firstElement-operator to achieve loading the first, if not available use second source. I would suggest to place an timeout on the observables and errorhandling. If the first one exits with an error, the second will not be called. There is no need to check for null, because null values are not allowed.

Lets have a look at the first test 'name': Two observables generate each a List. just1 produces the value first, so it will be used, the value from just2 will be discarded.

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    Observable<List<Integer>> just1 = Observable.just(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    Observable<List<Integer>> just2 = Observable.just(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

    TestObserver<List<Integer>> await = Observable.concat(just1, just2)
            .firstElement().test().await();

    List<Integer> collect = await.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertThat(collect).contains(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Test-2 will put the second value through, because just1 just completes without a value.

```
@Test
public void name2() throws Exception {
    Observable<List<Integer>> just1 = Observable.empty();
    Observable<List<Integer>> just2 = Observable.just(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

    TestObserver<List<Integer>> await = Observable.concat(just1, just2)
            .firstElement().test().await();

    List<Integer> collect = await.values().stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertThat(collect).contains(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Test-3 will not emit any values. On subscription to the 'Maybe' you will just receive an onComplete.

```
@Test
public void name3() throws Exception {
    Observable<List<Integer>> just1 = Observable.empty();
    Observable<List<Integer>> just2 = Observable.empty();

    TestObserver<List<Integer>> await = Observable.concat(just1, just2)
            .firstElement()
            .test()
            .await()
            .assertNoValues();
}
```

Test 4 will not emit any values because on the of the observables passes an onError.

```
@Test
public void name4() throws Exception {
    Observable<List<Integer>> just1 = Observable.empty();
    Observable<List<Integer>> just2 = Observable.error(NoSuchElementException::new);

    TestObserver<List<Integer>> await = Observable.concat(just1, just2)
            .firstElement()
            .test()
            .await()
            .assertNoValues()
            .assertError(NoSuchElementException.class);
}
```

Comment: Hans, it's not exactly what I was asking about. Thank you for your time.